# No microphone / headset function for Pixel Buds A-Series with pulseaudio / Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and trying to use my Pixel Buds A-Series as headset.
It works perfectly fine as audio sink / headphones, but I can't switch the Profile to 'headset' (in order to get the microphone to work)

It detects the profiles a2dp_sink and headset_head_unit but the later is shown with 'avaliable:no'

when I try to switch the profile to headset_head_unit:

```
pactl set-card-profile 24 headset_head_unit
```

i get:

```
Failure: Input/Output error
```

Here is the output of pactl (personal information replaced with xxxx)

pactl list

```
Card #24
    Name: bluez_card.xxxxxx
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 51
    Properties:
        device.description = "xxxxx Pixel Buds A-Series"
        device.string = "xxxxxx"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_xxxxx"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "xxx's Pixel Buds A-Series"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Profiles:
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: a2dp_sink
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): a2dp_sink, headset_head_unit
        headset-input: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
```

Comment: The version in use is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, it's a desktop system. Sorry, I was not aware of the distinction, thanks for clarification. I updated the original question with the version in use.

Comment: Facing same issue. As per https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg511415.html , one is supposed to change the Bluetooth profile from High Fidelity Playback to Headset Head Unit in order to get the mic input option to show up, however the change did not persist for me and did not get the mic input option.